# Sql get first 2 groups of a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a number formatted in the following manner:   123.456.789.1.2.3

I want a function that retrieves the first 2 groups of the number and puts them in a bigint: result: 123456

What I've done so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bl.fn_get_2_groups
(
@str nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS bigint
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @newStr nvarchar(255)
select @newStr = SUBSTRING(@str,1,charindex('.',@str)-1),  @str =  SUBSTRING(@str,charindex('.',@str)+1,LEN(@str))
select @newStr += SUBSTRING(@str,1,charindex('.',@str)-1)   
return convert(bigint,@newStr)

END GO
```

Does anyone know a different way to do this? Maybe more elegant or shorter?

Comment: the first two numbers have always 3 digits or can have more/less?

Comment: CoroveiAndrei use the @dasblinkenlight answer. It's right! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
cast(REPLACE(LEFT(@str,CHARINDEX('.', @str,CHARINDEX('.', @str)+1)),'.','') as bigint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method looks OK.  If you want something much more elegant or easier, I think you are going to have to write a CLR function. Then, you could avail yourself of all that .NET API has to offer for string parsing. Alternatively, you could try to do this parsing in the application layer. Of course, that may not be feasible.

You can read about regexs and CLR functions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Also, I would suggest amending  your SQL UDF to ensure that the input string does in fact have two periods.